# What Lie supergroup does the super-Poincare algebra generate?

Tags: supersymmetry, group-theory, lie-algebra

Every [Lie supergroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup_(physics)) has an associated [Lie superalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) of generators (in general, some of which are bosonic and some fermionic).  Which Lie supergroup(s) are generated by the [Super-Poincare algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra) for $d$ spacetime dimensions and $N$ spinor generators (or, if $d \equiv 2 \text{ mod } 4$, $M$ left-handed and $N$ right-handed spinor generators)?

Comment: In 4 dimensions, it is Inonu-Wigner contracted $OSP(4/N)$.

Comment: @ved Reference?

Comment: Castellani, Auria, Fre, supergravity and superstrings: a geometric perspective, Vol. 1, Part 2.

Comment: See also http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.523108.