# Is it possible to put a supersymmetric theory on a lattice?

Tags: supersymmetry, group-theory, lattice-model, poincare-symmetry

Several lattice models have recently been shown to display *emergent* supersymmetry at length scales long enough that the lattice can be coarse-grained into a continuum (e.g. see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7449), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4497), and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05192)).  Could a lattice model display *exact* supersymmetry even at the lattice length scales?  Clearly the answer is no, because the lattice breaks the Poincare subgroup of the supersymmetry group down to $S \times \mathbb{R}$, where $S$ is the lattice's space group and the $\mathbb{R}$ corresponds to time translational invariance.

According to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300137/what-lie-supergroup-does-the-super-poincare-algebra-generate), the supersymmetry Lie supergroup $G$ corresponding to 3+1D SUSY with $N$ fermionic generators and no additional internal symmetries is Inonu-Wigner contracted $OSP(4/N)$.  Does there exist a Hamiltonian, defined on a lattice with space group $S$, with a symmetry Lie supergroup $H < G$ such that the bosonic part of $H$ is $S \times \mathbb{R}$ and the fermionic part of $H$ is nontrivial?  (In other words, I want to reduce the full supersymmetry supergroup $G$ down to a sub-supergroup $H$, such that the bosonic part of $G$ reduces from the Poincare group down to a lattice space group (times time translation), but *without* reducing the fermionic part all the way down to the identity, which would eliminate the supersymmetry entirely.)  This seems to me like the natural way to restrict supersymmetry to a lattice.

Comment: Check out this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08591 . In a precise sense, the half-translation of certain 1d Majorana models is a supersymmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" Could a lattice model display exact supersymmetry even at the lattice length scales? Clearly the answer is no."

Yes, you are correct. In general, it is not possible. However, in some theories with extended supersymmetry, it is possible to maintain an exact nilpotent scalar supercharge exactly on the lattice. One can view this construction as follows - 1) take a continuum theory with sufficient number of supersymmetries, 2) twist the theory to get a topological field theory.
In flat space-time, this twisting is just a rewriting of the origin untwisted theory. Then, one can preserve a $\mathcal{Q}$, where $\mathcal{Q}^{2} = 0$. This prescription is valid for some theories, for ex: $\mathcal{N} = (2,2)$ SYM in two dimensions has now been studied on the lattice by various groups and in fact, in this theory one recovers all four supercharges as we take the continuum limit. In higher dimensions, this is still ongoing work. See this review : https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4881

The ultimate goal is to study $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM in four dimensions. However, it seems that just by maintaining 1/16 of the supersymmetries on the lattice exactly, recovering other 15/16 is not an easy task.

Comment: Probably this is related to the chiral anomaly, no?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I think the answer is yes, there does exist a Hamiltonian with a lattice supersymmetry as you described. One possible example is the **supersymmetric quantum mechanics on a lattice** proposed by **Witten**¹. In this model, the Hamiltonian is given by

$$H = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \left( p_n^2 + W'(q_n)^2 \right) + \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^N \left( W(q_{n+1}) - W(q_n) \right)^2$$

where $p_n$ and $q_n$ are canonical variables satisfying $[q_n,p_m] = i \delta_{nm}$, and $W(q)$ is a smooth function called the **superpotential**. The fermionic part of the supersymmetry algebra is generated by two operators $Q$ and $Q^\dagger$, which are defined as

$$Q = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{n=1}^N \left( p_n + i W'(q_n) \right) \psi_n$$
$$Q^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{n=1}^N \left( p_n - i W'(q_n) \right) \psi_n^\dagger$$

where $\psi_n$ and $\psi_n^\dagger$ are fermionic operators satisfying $\{\psi_n,\psi_m\} = 0$, $\{\psi_n^\dagger,\psi_m^\dagger\} = 0$, and $\{\psi_n,\psi_m^\dagger\} = \delta_{nm}$. The bosonic part of the supersymmetry algebra is generated by the Hamiltonian $H$, which satisfies

$$H = Q Q^\dagger + Q^\dagger Q$$
$$[H,Q] = [H,Q^\dagger] = 0$$
$$\{Q,Q\} = \{Q^\dagger,Q^\dagger\} = 0$$

The lattice space group $S$ in this model is the cyclic group $C_N$, which acts on the lattice sites by cyclic permutations. The time translation group $R$ acts on the Hamiltonian by unitary evolution. The symmetry Lie supergroup $H$ of this model is a sub-supergroup of the full supersymmetry supergroup $G$, which preserves the bosonic part $S\times R$ and has a nontrivial fermionic part generated by $Q$ and $Q^\dagger$. This model can be generalized to higher dimensions and more complex lattices, as discussed in this paper.

¹: Witten, E. (1982). Dynamical breaking of supersymmetry. Nuclear Physics B, 188(3), 513-554.

²: Catterall, S., & Kaplan, D. B. (2007). Exact lattice supersymmetry. Physics Reports, 484(1-2), 71-130.

Comment: The word "lattice" does not even occur in the paper by Witten, and neither paper uses supergroups